# Fastest way to remove a Collection of Longs from another in Java

Tags: java

I have two collections of `Long` type. Both of size **20-30** million. What is the quickest way to remove from one, those that are common in the second? Lesser the heap space taken, the better, as there are other things going on in parallel.

I know `LinkedList` is better than `ArrayList` for removals using Iterator, but I'm just not sure if I need to iterate over each element. I want to poll for any better approaches, both `Collections` are sorted.

**Edit**: I previously stated my collection sizes as 2-3 million, I realized it is **20-30** million.
There will be lots of overlaps. The exact type of Collections is open to debate as well.

Comment: If they're sorted you can use a normal binary lookup to find the elements to remove from the second. Obviously you'll need to iterate over the collection of numbers to be removed.

Comment: At that size, the exact type of collection matters a lot.

Comment: re: exact type of collection & heapspace: [trove](http://java-performance.info/primitive-types-collections-trove-library/) for example provides "collection" implementations for primitive types  that don't use lots of wrapper objects. Saves a lot of heap space, speed wise no idea.

Comment: How much of an overlap is expected? If not many, you can build a Bloom-filter for the second collection and use it to rule out elements that need to be removed. If the second collection is constant (or never has elements removed), even better.

Comment: @bizclop LOTS of overlap expected

Answer (score 1):

With counts in the range of millions, solutions with O(n<sup>2</sup>) complexity should be out. You have two basic solutions here:

- Sort the second collection, and use binary search for an O((N+M)*logM) solution, or
- Put elements from the second collection into a hash container, for an O(N+M) solution

Above, N is the number of elements in the first collection, and M is the number of elements in the second collection.

```
Set<Long> toRemove = new HashSet<Long>(collection2);
Iterator<Long> iter = collection1.iterator();
while (iter.hasNext()) {
    if (toRemove.contains(iter.next())) {
        iter.remove();
    }
}
```

Note that if `collection1` is an `ArrayList`, this will be very slow. If you must keep it an `ArrayList`, you can do it like this:

```
int rd = 0, wr = 0;
// Copy the elements you are keeping into a contiguous range
while (rd != arrayList1.size()) {
    Long last = arrayList1.get(rd++);
    if (!toRemove.contains(iter.next()) {
        arrayList1.put(wr++, last);
    }
}
// Remove "tail" elements
while (rd > wr) {
    arrayList1.remove(--wr);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Without growing heap.

```
Collection<Long> a = new HashSet<Long>();
//fill a
Collection<Long> b = new ArrayList<Long>();
//fill b
for(int i = 0; i < b.size(); i++){
    a.remove(b.get(i));
}
```

`b.size()` and `b.get(int i)` runs in constant time according to Oracles Javadoc.
Also `a.remove(O o)` runs in constant time.

Comment: I am looking for soemthing better performing than removeAll of ArrayList. My collection sizes being relatively large.

Answer (score 0):

First port of call would be the [Collection.removeAll](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/) method. This uses no extra heap space, and its time complexity is dependent on the performance of the `contains` method on your second collection. If your second collection is a TreeSet then `a.removeAll(b)` takes `O(n . log(m))` time (where n is the size of a and m is the size of b), if b is a HashSet then it takes `O(n)` time, if b is a sorted ArrayList then it's `O(nm)`, but you can create a new wrapper Collection that uses a binary search to reduce it to `O(n . log(m))` for negligible constant memory cost:

```
private static class SortedList<T extends Comparable<? super T>> extends com.google.common.collect.ForwardingList<T>
{

    private List delegate;

    public SortedList(ArrayList<T> delegate)
    {
        this.delegate = delegate;
    }

    @Override
    protected List<T> delegate()
    {
        return delegate;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean contains(Object object)
    {
        return Collections.binarySearch(delegate, (T) object) >= 0;
    }
}

static <E extends Comparable<? super E>> void removeAll(Collection<E> a, ArrayList<E> b)
{
    //assumes that b is sorted
    a.removeAll(new SortedList<E>(b));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at [Apache Common Collections](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/collections4/ListUtils.html#subtract(java.util.List,%20java.util.List))

I tested it with LinkedList containing ~3M Longs, it gives pretty good results :

```
    Random r = new Random();
    List<Long> list1 = new LinkedList<Long>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 3000000; i++) {
        list1.add(r.nextLong());
    }
    List<Long> list2 = new LinkedList<Long>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 2000000; i++) {
        list2.add(r.nextLong());
    }

    Collections.sort(list1);
    Collections.sort(list2);

    long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
    list3 = ListUtils.subtract(list2, list1);
    System.out.println("listUtils.intersection = " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - time));
```

I can't ensure you this is the best solution, but it is as easy one.

I get an execution time equals to :

```
1247 ms
```

Inconvenient : it creates a new List